# HTML Send Email

Tags: javascript, html, email

I currently have a website with an input and a button on it. When the button is clicked, I want to have the input sent to me through email.

How can I send an email through HTML. I have seen other examples with using href mailto to send emails but what I want is not a link but when the code is run, send an email to myself.

Another option is through JavaScript

Comment: You can't do this with only html. That's probably why every body is closing you. You have to submit to some form. Look at PHP or something simple to try it.

Answer (score 0):

[php is (probably) the easiest way](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), you can't do this with vanilla HTML